# C++ OpenGL SDL Screen Trouble

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'm back again with probably what is a small problem that I can't seem to work out whilst undertaking my OpenGL/SDL adventure.

This program brings up a 640x480px SDL screen, but there is nothing inside it, not even a background, it is just transparent through to whatever is on the screen behind it and I have to admit, I am unsure why albeit it's probably another silly mistake.

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

SDL_Event event;

int main (int argc, char **argv)

{

bool quit = false;

init();
draw_square(0,0,0);

while (quit == false)

    {

        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )

            {

                quit = true;

            }

    }

SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}

void init ()

{

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_OPENGL);
SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL );

glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( 0, 0 , 640 , 480, 0, 1 );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

}

void draw_square (int x, int y, int z)

{

glTranslatef(x,y,z);

glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex3f(0, 0 ,0);
    glVertex3f(50,0 ,0);
    glVertex3f(50,50,0);
    glVertex3f(0, 50,0);

glEnd();

glPushMatrix();

}
```

Many thanks ~ Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't clear the screen despite setting the clear colour. You need a call like glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); to actually do the clearing.

Also, it is best to continuously render inside of the loop if you want to do anything other than static drawing... it is likely you see nothing at all because its expecting you to do double buffered drawing with this in mind and needs you to swap the buffers to see the results on screen. Typically this is done each time through the loop after all of the draw calls have been made. I believe you can do this with [SDL_GL_SwapBuffers](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GL_SwapBuffers)

Comment: Ah thank you! I totally forgot about the existence of those functions.. Back to the drawing board for me!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help solve this. OpenGL can be confusing - add the layer of SDL and it becomes all the more confusing...

Answer (score 0):

You passed 0 for the alpha in the call to [glClearColor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml).  Try "1".

That makes the entire screen transparent.  I wouldn't have expected that to actually work, though, so good to know. :)

Comment: I changed it, I am still getting no screen. After running it, I wondered if this maybe the problem: Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 15 seconds). I'm fairly certain the while loop wouldn't be a problem but could it be?

Comment: For this to work you need to aquire a framebuffer config with an alpha channel and a compositing window manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

SDL_Event event;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool quit = false;
```

You should really call SDL_Init here, not delegating it into some init function. Otherwise somebode (you?) may change when init gets called and breaks your program. Really, your main function is your init function. Window creation should happen in a function called `create_window` or something like that.

```
    init();
```

Technically calling draw_square, or any drawing function outside the event loop calls for trouble. The effect you see: Well that happens if your window gets exposed (initially shown), but any events informing the program, that the contents need be updated, because they were overwritten, have no effect. Always call drawing functions from within the event loop. For static draws in reaction to draw events, for animated scenes in the idle section.

```
    draw_square(0,0,0);

    while (quit == false) {
        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
            quit = true;
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

void init ()    
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_OPENGL);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL );
```

This is the most common newbie misconception, that OpenGL is "initialized". The following calls are meant to be called for *scene setup*, i.e. at the beginning of the drawing function.

You also lack:

- setting the viewport
- actually clearing the scene (*glClearColor* only tells, which color to clear to, at the actual clearing call; technically it just sets some "register", but doesn't execute).

So those should not be called here

```
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, 0 , 640 , 480, 0, 1 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void draw_square (int x, int y, int z) {

    glTranslatef(x,y,z);

    glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glVertex3f(0, 0 ,0);
        glVertex3f(50,0 ,0);
        glVertex3f(50,50,0);
        glVertex3f(0, 50,0);

    glEnd();
```

The next line is a big **WTF**?!

```
    glPushMatrix();
```

Every matrix stack push must be balanced with a pop operationg (glPopMatrix). However pushing the matrix only makes sense if it is followed by some transformation. Which it isn't. If you called draw_square in a loop, you'd exhaust the maximum matrix stack depth within between 32 to 128 iteration (more likely on the lower numbers).

```
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do not worry I know I am missing the viewport and I know having glPushMatrix at the end of a function called "draw_square" isn't good without a glPopMatrix. I was simply playing about and testing in this program. Thank you for the explanation on drawing within the loop, that has helped my understanding. I will need additional event handlers though?

Comment: The SDL offers "window events" http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_WindowEvent drawing should happen in response to SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED